# How to restrict a draggable UIView to specific bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIImageView` which I have made Draggable via a custom class called `DraggableImageView2`.  The class is then instantiated in a `UIViewController` with an image and can be dragged within a `UIView`.  The thing is I want to restrict the `UIImageView` not to go past the specific boundaries when dragged.  Here is my current code:

```
import UIKit

class DraggableImageView2: UIImageView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter : CGPoint?

    var dragGesture: UIGestureRecognizer!
    var zoomGesture: UIGestureRecognizer!

    var lastKnownCenterX: CGFloat = 0.0
    var lastKnownCenterY: CGFloat = 0.0

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.initializeGestures()

    }


    override init(image: UIImage?) {

        super.init(image: image)

        self.initializeGestures()

    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.initializeGestures()

    }

    func initializeGestures() {

        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.multipleTouchEnabled = true

        dragGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DraggableImageView.handlePan(_:)))

        self.addGestureRecognizer(dragGesture)

    }

    func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!) {

        Scripts.log("PAN >>> MOVE ACTIVATED")

        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {

            let locationInView = recognizer.locationInView(superview)
            dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter = CGPoint(x: locationInView.x - center.x, y: locationInView.y - center.y)

            return

        }

        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

            dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter = nil

            return
        }

        let locationInView = recognizer.locationInView(superview)

        Scripts.log("PAN LOCATION >>> X = \(self.frame.origin.x) | Y = \(self.frame.origin.y) | LX = \(locationInView.x) | LY = \(locationInView.y) | DX = \(self.dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter!.x) | DY = \(self.dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter!.y)")

        let xDragMin: CGFloat = 1.0
        let yDragMin: CGFloat = 1.0
        let xDragMax: CGFloat = kDEVICE_WIDTH - self.frame.size.width - 1.0
        let yDragMax: CGFloat = kDEVICE_WIDTH - self.frame.size.height - 1.0

        var newCenterX: CGFloat = locationInView.x - self.dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter!.x
        var newCenterY: CGFloat = locationInView.y - self.dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter!.y

        if self.frame.origin.x < xDragMin {

            Scripts.log("PAN LOCATION >>> X MIN PAST BOUNDS")

            newCenterX =  lastKnownCenterX

        }

        if self.frame.origin.y < yDragMin {

            Scripts.log("PAN LOCATION >>> Y MIN PAST BOUNDS")

            newCenterY = lastKnownCenterY

        }

        if self.frame.origin.x > xDragMax {

            Scripts.log("PAN LOCATION >>> X MAX PAST BOUNDS")

        }

        if self.frame.origin.y > yDragMax {

            Scripts.log("PAN LOCATION >>> Y MAX PAST BOUNDS")

        }


        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1) {
            self.center = CGPoint(x: newCenterX,
                                  y: newCenterY)
        }

        lastKnownCenterX = newCenterX
        lastKnownCenterY = newCenterY

    }


    func handlePinch(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer!) {

        Scripts.log("PINCH >>> ZOOM ACTIVATED")

        //self.bringSubviewToFront(recognizer.view!)

        recognizer.view?.transform = CGAffineTransformScale((recognizer.view?.transform)!, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)
        recognizer.scale = 1

    }

    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        Scripts.log("shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer WAS CALLED")

        return true

    }

}
```

I've only started working on the `xDragMin` and `yDragMin` portion.  Everything works for stopping it when it is less than the **`xDragMin`**, but the problem becomes for some strange reason, when you try to drag out of it, it gets frozen in that X Point.  Same for the **`yDragMin`**, one if reaches the min, it stops as it should, but can't drag out of the Y Point.

Comment: Can you try logging `lastKnownCenterX` and `lastKnownCenterY`? If those values somehow got set to something less than `xDragMin` or `xDragY` then your view's frame would most definitely get stuck in that position.

Comment: @KyleParent just tried logging it.  No, doesn't seem like the last known points were set less than the Drag Min Points.  Here is a sample output where it froze: LAST KNOWN LOCATION :PRE: >>> X = 56.75 | Y = 301.75 
LAST KNOWN LOCATION :POST: >>> X = 56.75 | Y = 301.75

Comment: What is the view's `frame.origin.x` when `lastKnownCenterX` is 56.75?

Comment: Ah, so my suspicion is correct - somehow your view is being allowed to pass the `xDragMin` threshold. Once that happens, you will always hit the first conditional and set `newCenterX =  lastKnownCenterX`, where `lastKnownCenterX` is already too far to the left. I would recommend revisiting the logic you use to calculate `newCenterX` and `newCenterX`. Shouldn't it be `var newCenterX: CGFloat = locationInView.x + self.dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter!.x`?

Comment: @KyleParent That didn't work, but your clues and suggestions I think have helped me identify what I think the problem is especially after adding more logs.  The issue I think is this logic "if self.frame.origin.x < xDragMin".  This condition is perfectly fine until it hits the bounds.  Once it does then self.frame.origin.x will never change (DUH) cos now it's position is fixed.  I need another condition to check that once the bounds has been hit, check if the users touch is moving in a +ve direction.  If so, then unlock the x position....sounds good on paper, now I have to figure out the code.

Comment: @KyleParent I seem to have found the fix, I've added my fix.

Comment: @Lavvo have you got Solution ?

Answer (score 0):

So after some more digging and playing around, I seem to have been able to solve my own problem, at least for the X Bounds Min.  Here is what I did:

(1) Added these new variables

```
var isWithinXBounds: Bool = true
var lastKnownLX: CGFloat = 0.0
```

(2) The logic starting with "if self.frame.origin.x < xDragMin" needed to be fine tuned. This condition is perfectly fine until it hits the X bounds. Once it does then self.frame.origin.x will never change (DUH) cos now its position is locked. I need another condition to check that once the bounds has been hit i.e. locked, check if the users touch is moving in a +ve direction. If so, then set the BOOL value back to TRUE which will unlock the x position

```
  if self.frame.origin.x < xDragMin {

        Scripts.log("PAN LOCATION >>> X MIN PAST BOUNDS")

        self.isWithinXBounds = false

        //If TOUCH still moving in negative direction
        if locationInView.x - lastKnownLX  < 0 {

            newCenterX =  lastKnownCenterX

        }
        else {

            self.isWithinXBounds = true

        }

    }
```

(3) Here is the condition that will then unlock the UIImageView based on the BOOL value:

```
if isWithinXBounds {

        lastKnownCenterX = newCenterX
        lastKnownLX = locationInView.x

    }
```